# Background drawable shape margin

Tags: android

I have an xml drawable shape with rounded corners which is background of listview(with margin 10dp).
Now I added header/footer to the listview.

But how can I make background not affect header/footer? I want it to start from the first(not header) element in array and finish at the last(not footer). The size of items in listview is known.

Thanks!

Comment: show us some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide the code of your listView item XML and the listView adapter, i can give you a detailed answer.

basically this is what you have to do

1) in your listView item XML, add the header and footer. set id's and set the visibility property to `gone`

2) in your adapter, in the `getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method; check the position. if the position is 0, set the header visibility to `View.VISIBLE`

and if the position size is equal to the `getCount()`, set `View.VISIBLE` to the footer.